# New to XSLT trying to eliminate duplicate parents based on element value.but would like to merge the children

Tags: xslt-1.0

Here is my input xml, would like to eliminate `<SRNumber>1</SRNumber>` but merge the `childServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes`. Appreciate Any help, breaking my head on this for a day Input XML:

```
<ServiceRequest> <SRNumber>1</SRNumber> 
<ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes> 
<Note>Test1</Note> 
</ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes> 
</ServiceRequest> 
<ServiceRequest> 
<SRNumber>1</SRNumber> <ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes> <Note>Test2</Note> </ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes> </ServiceRequest> <ServiceRequest> <SRNumber>2</SRNumber> <ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes> <Note>Test3</Note> </ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes> </ServiceRequest>
```

....
        **Desired Output:**

```
<ServiceRequest> 
<SRNumber>1</SRNumber> 
<ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes> 
<Note>Test1</Note> 
</ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes> 
<ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes> 
<Note>Test2</Note> 
</ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes> 
<ServiceRequest> 
<SRNumber>2</SRNumber> 
<ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes>
<Note>Test3</Note> 
</ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes> 
</ServiceRequest>

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kSRByNum" match="ServiceRequest" use="SRNumber"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "ServiceRequest
    [generate-id()
    =
     generate-id(key('kSRByNum', SRNumber)[1])
    ]
 ">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="SRNumber"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
    "key('kSRByNum', SRNumber)/ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ServiceRequest"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML** (after corrections to make it well-formed):

```
<t>
    <ServiceRequest>
        <SRNumber>1</SRNumber>
        <ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes>
            <Note>Test1</Note>
        </ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes>
    </ServiceRequest>
    <ServiceRequest>
        <SRNumber>1</SRNumber>
        <ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes>
            <Note>Test2</Note>
        </ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes>
    </ServiceRequest>
    <ServiceRequest>
        <SRNumber>2</SRNumber>
        <ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes>
            <Note>Test3</Note>
        </ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes>
    </ServiceRequest>
</t>
```

**produce the wanted, correct result**:

```
<t>
   <ServiceRequest>
      <SRNumber>1</SRNumber>
      <ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes>
         <Note>Test1</Note>
      </ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes>
      <ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes>
         <Note>Test2</Note>
      </ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes>
   </ServiceRequest>
   <ServiceRequest>
      <SRNumber>2</SRNumber>
      <ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes>
         <Note>Test3</Note>
      </ServiceRequest_LXKCTrackCodes>
   </ServiceRequest>
</t>
```

**Explanation**: Appropriate use of **[Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)** and template matching.

Comment: @user1239213: If that was perfect, how about *accepting* the answer? This is done by clicking the check-mark next to the answer.